# Identifiying a topological space given by a quotient

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, low-dimensional-topology

Let be $\mathcal{D}^{2}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\}$ and $\mathcal{D}^{2}(\frac{1}{2})=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq \frac{1}{2}\}$. I'm asked to identify who is the collapse $\mathcal{D}^{2}/\mathcal{D}^{2}(\frac{1}{2})$. My intuition is that this quotient space is homeomorphic to the torus, but really I'm not able to show it.

The thing that I know is the following: let be $X$ a topological space, and $A$ a topological subspace, then the collapse of $A$ in $X$ is given by $\mathcal{R}$ where the classes are given by $[x]=\begin{cases}x, x\notin A\\ A, x\in A\end{cases}$.

Any hint to formalize this intuition is appreciated!

Comment: Picture a disk, and then collapse a smaller disk in the middle to a point. What does it look like?

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong @ElliotG but is the greater disk? Maybe I don't understand yet the "visual" interpretation of the collapse... Can you give me more examples? The examples that I have saw are for example. Let be the interval $[0,1]$, if I collapse it to the set $\{0, 1\}$ the what I have is $\mathbb{S}^{1}$, here it's easy, but in this case I don't see it...

Comment: You meant to say "quotient" where you have written "quotien"[sic], right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry ... @GeoffreyTrang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient is homeomorphic to the original closed disk.
As the inner disk that is collasped to a point p, is closed it is possible to place p on the real plane as a not isolated point.
The open sets of the quotient that contain p  correspond to the open sets of the original disk that contain the inner disk and those that do not contain p correspond to the open sets of the original disk that are disjoint to the inner disk.

Were the inner disk an open disk, then the quotient would be homeomorphic to a closed annulus with an isolated point.  It makes no difference topologically if the point is inside or outside the ring.